# I am trying to display an image once a checkbox is checked but the code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

Here is my code:

```
        <form>
            White
            <input id="white" type="checkbox" onclick="checkMe()"/>
            <img id="www" style="display: none;" src="assets/2.jfif" alt="shirt">
        </form>
        <script>
        function checkMe(){
            var cb = document.getElementById("white");
            var img = document.getElementById("www");
            if(cb.checked==true){
                text.style.display="block";
            } else {
                text.style.display="none";
            }
        }
        </script>
```

The checkbox is indicating that it is being checked but the image is not displaying. Ive tried possible solutions but none have helped. Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: `text` pops up from nowhere, maybe you meant `img` ..?

Comment: It's often helpful to use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to check whether there are any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
 text.style.display="block";
text.style.display="none";
```

Replace text with img

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cb = document.getElementById("white");
var img = document.getElementById("www");

function checkMe() {

  if (cb.checked == true) {
    img.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    img.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="white" type="checkbox" onclick="checkMe()" />
<img id="www" style="display: none;" src="https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-100kb.png" alt="shirt">
```

Simple Method - without Js

```css
img {
  display: none
}

input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

input:checked +img {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<img src="https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-100kb.png" >
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Just need to Replace the wrong selector with your image selector variable into the JavaScript function.**

Below Is the function I'm sharing with you. You should replace this function with the old one.

```
function checkMe() {
    var cb = document.getElementById("white");
    var img = document.getElementById("www");
    if (cb.checked == true) {
        img.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        img.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah took me a while to see it. Thanks